# I am passing a string from a stateful widget to stateful widget and I want it to be converted to int and store it in a variable

Tags: flutter

I am passing a string from a stateful widget to stateful widget, and I want it to be converted to int and store it in a variable so I can use it as a value for my index

```
        class RecordNumber extends StatefulWidget {
      final String recordName;
      const RecordNumber(this.recordName, {super.key});

      @override
      RecordNumberState createState() => RecordNumberState();
    }

    class RecordNumberState extends State<RecordNumber> {
      // I wanto initialize the variable recordName here as an integer
      // final int index = (the rocordName);
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Text(widget.recordName),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable in your state class

```
int recordNameIndex = 0;
```

In initState you can then parse your string to an int. You have to write widget before recordName, because your variable is in the widget class and not in the state

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   recordNameIndex = int.parse(widget.recordName);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can parse a string to an int with `int.parse()`

in your code it will be like this :

```
      final int index = int.parse(recordName);
```

as example:

```
      int.parse("102") == 102  // true
```